# How to Hide Context Menu in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have 2 menus in Plugin1 and same 2 in Plugin2.

For Product1 -> Included Plugin1
For Product2 -> Included both Plugin1 and Plugin2

Product1 is fine.
But in Product2 i wanted to hide context menus from Plugin1 and get the menus from Plugin2.

Currently both Context Menus from Plugin1 and Plugin2 are getting in Product2.
Both Plugin1 and Plugin2 contributing to the Product2. Please find the below attached image.

Since it is design issue. As of now i wanted to hide menus from Plugin1 because of dependency issue.

Is there any way to hide??

[Click here for Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFqa0.jpg)

Please help me.

Comment: Can you please provide more details of the issue? Please provide some screenshots if possible.

Comment: Hello, I have updated my description and attached a snap. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can access the implementation of ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor class in your product 2. If you have the access, you can add the menuitem control in the postWindowOpen method.

```
@Override
    public void postWindowOpen()
    {
        IMenuManager menuManager = getWindowConfigurer().getActionBarConfigurer().getMenuManager();

        for ( IContributionItem item : menuManager.getItems() )
        {
            if ( item instanceof MenuManager )
            {
                MenuManager mm = (MenuManager) item;
                if ( mm.getId().equals( "file" ) ) // change to your menuName in product 1
                {
                    mm.remove( "org.eclipse.ui.openLocalFile" ); // change to your menu item id in product1
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  CNF for contributing context menus, I hope this will helpful to fix the issue.

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent">
    <actionProvider
        class=".....ActionProvider"
        id="new_menu1"
        overrides="menu1">
        <enablement>
            <instanceof value="......" />
        </enablement>
    </actionProvider>
</extension>

public class ActionProvider extends CommonActionProvider {
// empty class
}
```